# Problema con formato moneda-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy tratando de implementar, la siguiente función para darle formato de moneda separado por coma  pero al ingresar la cantidad me pone comas donde no debería por ejemplo **75500** me lo pone asi **7,5,500**, me podrían ayudar

```js
$("#number").on({
  "keyup": function() {
  $("#number").val(numberWithCommas($("#number").val()));
  }
});
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ingrese la cantidad: <input id="number">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas casi ahí. Solo te falta una etapa para borrar las comas que ya has agregado, antes de darle formato nuevamente:

```js
$("#number").on({
  "keyup": function() {
  $("#number").val(numberWithCommas($("#number").val()));
  }
});
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ingrese la cantidad: <input id="number">
```

Comment: muchas gracias Alter!